# javascript skip duplicate permutation from array

Tags: javascript

I have an array with permutations but I need to remove duplicate permutations.

Permutations for 3 different digits is always 6 ways, so 345 and 453 are the same number. 497, 479 and 749 likewise would be considered the same number.

Also, 128, 281, 812, 182, 218 and 821 are all the same number.

It means I need to keep any only one permutation from 128, 281, 812, 182, 218 and 821 all others should be removed from the array.

Like if array has 497, 479, 749, 128, 281, 812, 182, 218, 821

output should be : 497, 128

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT:Post effort and code

Comment: so, you need to remove all duplicate anagram values?

Comment: @Tschallacka - looks like he needs to keep only ONE set of 3 digits

Comment: So keep the first found or keep the one in numerical order?

Comment: @mplungjan  yes right

Comment: i need keep only one value from same permutation other need to remove from array

Comment: what ever is first found keep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep the digits only, then you can sort before storing:

```js
var newList = [],
  list = [345, 453, 497, 479, 749, 128, 281, 812, 182, 218, 821, 128, 281, 812, 182, 218, 821, 497, 479, 749, 128, 281, 812, 182, 218, 821, 497, 128];
list.forEach(function(item) {
  var norm = +String(item).split("").sort().join("");
  if (newList.indexOf(norm) == -1) newList.push(norm); // or save item instead
})
console.log(newList);
```

Comment: Oh yeah :) This is really logical solution! Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the parts and maintain a hash object with the key of the sorted and joined parts.

```js
var array = [497, 479, 749, 128, 281, 812, 182, 218, 821].map(a => a.toString().split('')),
    hash = Object.create(null),
    unique = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    a.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
    })
    if (!hash[a.join('')]) {
        hash[a.join('')] = true;
        unique.push(a);
    }
});

console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make an outer loop that loops throuhg all the items once.

Then you need a loop that loops through already existing items.
In that inner loop you test the current outer loop item against an inner loop item.

You need to sort the individual characters/numbers so they are all the same.

You can do that by

- converting the number to string,
- then split it on every character,
- sort it,
- join it back to string
- and then compare them.

Things that are not an anagram can be pushed to the already existing items.

```js
//Test wether something is an anagram
function isAnagram(word1, word2) {
  var str1 = (word1 + "").split('').sort().join('').trim();
  var str2 = (word2 + "").split('').sort().join('').trim();
  return str1 === str2;
}
// testing array
var arr = [42, 48, 84, 128, 281, 812, 182, 218, 821];
// result array
var approved = [];
// loop through all items
for (var c = 0; c < arr.length; c++) {
  var test = arr[c];
  var good = true;
  // loop through all already approved items.
  for (var i = 0; i < approved.length; i++) {
    var against = approved[i];
    // if it's an anagram, don't add it.
    if (isAnagram(test, against)) {
      good = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  // if it wasn't flagged as an anagram, add it to approved.
  if (good) {
    approved.push(test);
  }
}
console.log(approved);
```

To get a bit more brevity and keep it all in one function call without external variables you can do:

```js
// testing array
var arr = [42, 48, 84, 128, 281, 812, 182, 218, 821];

var result = arr.reduce(function(exists, test) {
        if(!Array.isArray(exists)) {
           exists = [exists];
        }
        if(exists.filter(function(against) {
               var str1 = (test + "").split('').sort().join('').trim();
               var str2 = (against + "").split('').sort().join('').trim();
               return str1 === str2;
           }).length === 0) {
            exists.push(test);
        }
        return exists;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why don't you use `.filter`? Also, please, format the code

Comment: One can use filter, but I thought for the sake of explaining the logic the use of loops would be better, so it's easier to deduce the steps the computer makes.

Comment: Well, ok, but in real projects I wouldn't use that style

Comment: Me neither, but i'm not in the business of writing code for others for free ;-) I like to explain stuff and make it understandable.

Comment: I added a filter method @AlexSlipknot

Comment: @Tschallacka Nice :) But as you can see answer from **mplungjan** has a very interesting approach. To be honest if I post answer it might be similar to yours (second edition). But always can be a better way :)

Comment: the indexOf is a nice feature, and I would have gone with that to, if but @op didn't specify if order is truly irrelevant. just that he wanted the first match.

Comment: for example values 736 and 673 would both become 367. but what if that had been removed from the list beforehand because of reasons.